# How to show the tasklist in ranges using the PID?

Tags: batch-file

I need show the tasklist in ranges using the PID, show the process 10 in 10, but , I tried some like that:

---

```bat
@echo off
for /l  %%i in (0, 10, 100) do (
tasklist /NH /fi "PID ge %%i" /fi " PID le %%i+10")
```

Comment: I understand your question, but unfortunately do not understand the reason, or how you'd like the output to be viewed. Do you want to output ten tables, or do you want to output one table but provide a delay between each range. Can you please expand upon your question to show an example of the required output. Incidentally, the first range of ten would be `{0..9}`, the next `{10..19}`, the next `{20..29}`, the next `{30..39}`, the next `{40..49}`, the next `{50..59}`, the next `{60..69}`, the next `{70..79}`, the next `{80..89}` and the last `{90..99}`, what do you want to do with `PID` `100`?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I want to put all tasklist in ranges, for example: ranges 0 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30, all the tasklist, using the pid to sort it, PID 0, Name: system, Memory 889kb, i tried with a for, but, It still does not work

Comment: I'll ask again, How do you want the output to be viewed? Also `0` to `10` is a range of eleven, not ten! I've already shown you the ranges in my comment above.